# How to use secondary database tables in new module of drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am developing new site i want to tie with the site with another database. is there any posibility to use secondary database tables in new module of the site.

Comment: Refer to link : http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-7-connect-other-external-database